# Long polling not isseting timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**SERVER.PHP:**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
require 'pdo.php';
set_time_limit(0);
while ( true )
{
    $requestedTimestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? (int)$_GET['timestamp'] : null;
    clearstatcache();

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare( "SELECT * FROM publication WHERE publication_time >= :requestedTimestamp" );

    $stmt->bindParam( ':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp );
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($rowpublication = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $publication_id  = $rowpublication['publication_id'];
        }
        echo $publication_id;
        break;
    } else  {
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }
}
?>
```

**CLIENT.JS**

```
function getContent( timestamp )
{
    var queryString = { 'timestamp' : timestamp };

    $.get ( '/php-long-polling-master/server/server.php' , queryString , function ( data )
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $( '#response' ).html( obj.content );

        // reconecta ao receber uma resposta do servidor
        getContent( obj.timestamp );
    });
}

$( document ).ready ( function ()
{
    getContent();
});
```

Client.js sends request without query string: `server.php` instead of: `server.php?timestamp=XXXXXXXXXX`.

Any solution? I'm new in long polling.

Comment: in your first call to your function `getContent();` where is the `timestamp`?

Comment: How did you discover the query string is missing? On a side note, I'm confused why you have an infinite loop in server.php.

Comment: The php will do the loop until you find certain date with this timestamp, is a long polling;